# looping recordset PHP

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

I have just used this code in a project which works perfectly, but I have noticed that the first record is always not displayed. Eg. the SQL query lists 15 results, but the output only display 14, missing the first record. Any ideas why?

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query($sql);

//first put all the results into an array so we can look backward and see previous items
$resultSet = array();
while($record = mysql_fetch_array($rs2Dfiles)) {
$resultSet[] = $record;
}

for ( $i = 0 ; $i < count($resultSet) ; $i++ ) {
if ( $i == 0 ) {
//for the first item, show the category name
echo '<div class="Box"><div class="BoxHeader gfgreen"><h3>'.$resultSet[$i]['ftCatName'].'</h3>    </div>';
} else if ($resultSet[$i]['ftCatName'] != $resultSet[$i-1]['ftCatName']) {
//every time we encounter a new category, display a new line and show the category name
echo '</div><div class="Box"><div class="BoxHeader gfgreen"><h3>'.$resultSet[$i]  ['ftCatName'].'</h3></div>';
}

echo '<p class="Document"><a title="View file details" href="download.php?id='.$resultSet[$i]    ['DownloadID'].'">'.$resultSet[$i]['DownloadName'].'</a> ('.formatSize(    filesize('DOCS/'.$resultSet[$i]['DownloadFilename'].'')).')</p>';
}
echo '</div>';
?>
```

Comment: Give whole the code with query .....!

Comment: note: `mysql_*` is deprecated. You should start using `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a foreach, might make things easier?

```
$last = null;

foreach($resultSet as $resultRow)
{
    if ($resultRow != $last) 
    {
        echo 'your html content goes here';
        echo $resultRow['propertyName'];
    }

    $last = $resultRow
}
```